# FileStorage.read() occurred an error:The sequence element is not a numerical scalar?

Tags: c++, opencv

guys~
I'm not good at English, but I'll try my best to describe my question.

I'm using OpenCV2.4.9 FileStorage in OpenCV to store a Mat in a ".yml" file. And the file is 2.91G

The WRITE code like this:

```
fs.open(tempPath, FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "TF" << wordsFreq;
fs.release();
```

wordsFreq is a Mat

But when I use the followed code to read it back.

```
sprintf(tmpFileName,"%s/TF.yml",trainingResultsDir.c_str());
FileStorage fs(tmpFileName, FileStorage::READ);
fs["TF"] >> wordsFreq;
fs.release();
```

It occurred an error like this :

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The sequence element is not a numerical scalar) in cvReadRawDataSlice, file /Users/xuhuaiyu/Development/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 3362
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/xuhuaiyu/Development/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:3362: error: (-2) The sequence element is not a numerical scalar in function cvReadRawDataSlice
```

Comment: is tempPath equal to tmpFileName?

Comment: yes, tempPath equal to tmpFileName

Comment: it works for me... probably you are messing up something somewhere else in the code. Post a minimal example that reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks~I have tried a minimal example, but it works well...

Comment: When I use a minimal example , it won't get that error

Comment: So your error is somewhere else, not in the code of your minimal example, nor in the question

Comment: Can you give me some advice where I can test it?

Comment: I can't, I don't have your code :D. View your file in some editor when the subsequent read will crash, and see if it's well formatted

Comment: Thanks a lot~I'll try.